# алгоритм Джея Кадане,нахождение подмассива максимальной суммы..Нужно кое что разжевать

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм, динамическое-программирование

Сам алгоритм выглядит следующим образом. Будем идти по массиву и накапливать в некоторой переменной s текущую частичную сумму. Если в какой-то момент s окажется отрицательной, то мы просто присвоим s=0. Утверждается, что максимум из всех значений переменной s, случившихся за время работы, и будет ответом на задачу.

Докажем этот алгоритм.

В самом деле, рассмотрим первый момент времени, когда сумма s стала отрицательной. Это означает, что, стартовав с нулевой частичной суммы, мы в итоге пришли к отрицательной частичной сумме — значит, и весь этот префикс массива, равно как и любой его суффикс имеют отрицательную сумму. Следовательно, от всего этого префикса массива в дальнейшем не может быть никакой пользы: он может дать только отрицательную прибавку к ответу.

Однако этого недостаточно для доказательства алгоритма. В алгоритме мы, фактически, ограничиваемся в поиске ответа только такими отрезками, которые начинаются непосредственно после мест, когда случалось s<0.

Но, в самом деле, рассмотрим произвольный отрезок [l;r], причём l не находится в такой "критической" позиции (т.е. l > p+1, где p — последняя такая позиция, в которой s<0). 
?.........Не понятно тут,почему к позиции p  прибавляют единицу?

Далее:Поскольку последняя критическая позиция находится строго раньше, чем в l-1, то получается, что сумма a[p+1.... l-1] неотрицательна. Это означает, что, сдвинув l в позицию p+1, мы увеличим ответ или, в крайнем случае, не изменим его.
?.........Здесь не ясно почему теперь из l  вычитают единицу.. И конец абзаца тоже не ясен,зачем сдвигать l  в позицию p+1?

Далее:Так или иначе, но получается, что действительно при поиске ответа можно ограничиться только отрезками, начинающимися сразу после позиций, в которых оказывалось s<0. Это доказывает правильность алгоритма.
Код алгоритма на С,в котором я до сих пор не могу понять что значит "ans"?Я его реализую(если реализую конечно) сам на другом языке.

```
int ans = a[0],
        ans_l = 0,
        ans_r = 0,
        sum = 0,
        minus_pos = -1;
    for (int r=0; r<n; ++r) {
        sum += a[r];

        if (sum > ans) {
            ans = sum;
            ans_l = minus_pos + 1;
            ans_r = r;
        }

        if (sum < 0) {
            sum = 0;
            minus_pos = r;
}
}
```

Зачем нужна переменная  минимальной позиции равной -1?Проще весь код наверно будет объяснить(... заранее благодарю.. если время найдёте мне его разжевать...`введите сюда код`

Answer (score 3):

В `ans` запоминается максимальное значение суммы (гляньте - ее значение обновляется только когда `sum` его превышает. При этом в `ans_r` запоминается соответствующий индекс. Ну, а `minus_pos` - соответственно запоминает, где последний раз значение суммы (с учетом обнуления) отрицательное было. Если такого ни разу не было - `minus_pos` будет иметь *несуществующее* значение индекса -1.